# Gatsby develop command fails on macOS High Sierra, no error message shown

Tags: bash, cmd, gatsby, macos-high-sierra

I'm very new to Gatsby and have just started reading up on the website's tutorial [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/). However, I'm having some trouble running the `gatsby develop` command as it throws an error and displays only this message and nothing else:

```
Looks like develop for this site is already running, can you visit http://://localhost:8000 ? If it is not, try again in five seconds!
```

When I click on http://://localhost:8000, the page just says localhost refused to connect.

Below is the output of `gatsby info -C`:

```
  System:
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2415M CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.4.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.14 - /usr/local/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 85.0.4183.102
    Safari: 11.1.2   
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.24.54 => 2.24.54   
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.94
```

I've also tried uninstalling and installing the gatsby-cli, but the issue persists. Also checked if anything's running on port 8000 using `lsof -i TCP:8000`, but nothing came up.

If someone could shed some light as to where the issue's coming from, I'd greatly appreciate it!

PS: I tried running `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve`, and encountered no problems.

Comment: You can check out different solutions for different causes of the same problem over here
https://silentlad.com/looks-like-develop-for-this-site-is-already-running-can-you-visit-http:localhost:8000-if-it-is-not-try-again-in-five-seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the port of the [OS firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642). You can easily fix it by adding a port to the default Gatsby running command (in your `package.json`):

```
gatsby develop -p 8001
```

Note the `-p` flag, as you can see in [the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-cli/#options) it change Gatsby's running port. Of course, you can change the `8001` for any desired (and unused) port. Changing it won't affect the Gatsby project because it will readapt the GraphQL playground to it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'd have to open port `8000` on the [firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642).

On OSX this should be `pfctl` & `/etc/pf.conf`.

Comment: When I do `gatsby develop -p80` I get `Something is already running at port 80`. But port 80 is not blocked. Does your answer help? Do I need a param for `pfctl`?